# Instagram /users/{user-id}/media/recent APINotAllowedError

Tags: instagram-api

I'm trying to fetch posts of the users whom I follow in instagram. I've created the app, I receive valid access token, app is running in the sandbox mode. I've added a user in the sandbox, whom I follow, as in sandbox only sandbox user data is available for viewing. What I'm trying is to fetch user's follow list, that is successfully done through `users/self/follows?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN` request, which succeeds and I already have the user id. Then I'm trying to call `/users/{user-id}/media/recent` for getting that user's recent media. I believe this should work, as I'm following that user and that user has approved my follow request. However the request fails telling following

```
{
  "meta": {
    "error_type": "APINotAllowedError",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "you cannot view this resource"
  }
}
```

Some details how I've configured the instagram app.
The scope that I use is `basic+public_content+follower_list`.
I don't use implicit authentication, and have custom backend to handle authentication with client_secret.

Also, I know an app [Followers+](https://itunes.apple.com/ae/app/followers-+-for-instagram/id566223681?mt=8) which can read the media of each user you follow. So this should be something that is possible to do, and I don't know why I can't do that.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks the error you get if user is private, if the user is private, then you cannot access the user via API even if you are approved to follow by that user. This was a new change in API post June 1, 2016.

The only way to access private users is to use Instagram app or instagram.com

Comment: what is username, i can check

Comment: @kristak where did you find that info related to API Change? I can't find it anywhere. I am in the same position, the user I follow but the API returns 400 even if in official Instagram app I can see his details.

Comment: I had contacted instagram and they have confirmed it is expected behavior for API, it was changed cause 3rd-party apps were caching private profile photos and it appeared in google image search and people were complaining. So APIs does not give access to private user profile.

Comment: @kirsrak many thanks for taking your time to answer me. What about seeing followers/following lists from other users, except for the logged in user? I suppose that this is also a change from 1st June? When I try to see somebody's followers, I get the same error.

Comment: yes, instagram API no longer allows accessing other user's following list